# Calling a method from a different class within an accessor of another class (homework)

Tags: java

I had a hard time with the problem and I also had a hard time looking for solutions online. How do you call setYear/setMonth/setDay from the test class (test class cannot be altered) in the CollegeStudent class?

Still had not run the test code since there are errors whenever I try to run the code since I need to find a solution with the setYear/setMonth/setDay  :(

*Correct me if I'm wrong with the terms*

*Sorry for my bad english*

MyData and CollegeStudent is my code while the Test class is from my prof which should be used to test my code

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]){
    CollegeStudent cs = new CollegeStudent("Cruz","Tom", new MyDate(2014, 6, 1));


    cs.getEnrollmentDate().setYear(2018);
    cs.getEnrollmentDate().setMonth(11);
    cs.getEnrollmentDate().setDay(31);

    cs.getGraduationDate().setYear(2023);
    cs.getGraduationDate().setMonth(3);
    cs.getGraduationDate().setDay(32);
}


public class MyDate{
    private int month, year, day;

    public MyDate(int year, int month, int day){
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
        this.day = day;
    }
    public void setYear(int year){
        this.year = year;
    }
    public void setMonth(int month){
        this.month = month;
    }
    public void setDay(int day){
        this.day = day;
    }
}

public class CollegeStudent{
        private String first_name, last_name, enrollment_date, graduation_date;

        public MyDate o;

        public void CollegeStudent(String first_name, String last_name, MyDate mydate){
            this.first_name = first_name;
            this.last_name = last_name;
            o = mydate;
        }

        public void setFirstname(String first_name){
            this.first_name = first_name;
        }
        public String getFirstname(){
            return first_name;
        }
        public void setLastname(String last_name){
            this.last_name = last_name;
        }
        public String getLastname(){
            return last_name;
        }
        public void setEnrollmentDate(MyDate mydate){
            this.enrollment_date = mydate.dateToString();
        }
        public String getEnrollmentDate(){
            return enrollment_date;
        }
        public void setGraduationDate(MyDate mydate){
            this.graduation_date = mydate.dateToString();
        }
        public String getGraduationDate(){
            return graduation_date;
        }
}
```

Comment: `enrollment_date` and `graduation_date` are currently strings on your code, they don't have `year`, `month` and `day` methods.

Comment: `cs.getEnrollmentDate().setYear(2018);` first function `getEnrollmentDate` returns `String` and then then you are calling `setYear` on top of that that is why you are getting an error

Comment: Simply storing `enrollment_date` and `graduation_date` as the "MyDate" instead of String makes it much easier (and returning the MyDate from the get methods instead of strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot work, because with the getter method, you get the result as a string. But you want to have the MyDate. So change the type of the variable and the methods. So it works.

```
public void setEnrollmentDate(MyDate mydate){
     this.enrollment_date = mydate;
}

public MyDate getEnrollmentDate(){
     return enrollment_date;
}
```

You can do the same for the graduation_date.